# c++ DirectX 11 source code samples/examples?

Tags: c++, directx-11

My question for you guys are really about more resources. Ive gotten stuck in my homework and my school wants me to do stuff with shaders but has frank d luna as a resource which is all written in effect files. Which source code I might add, does not seem to work for most people, including myself. Im trying to learn more about 3d programming and trying to create a simple grid/terrain area but it is super hard to find simple and educative source code.

I got the book of Frank D luna which to be honest havent entirely helpful. Everything is in effect files which is to my understanding obsolete and is still slightly different compared to vertex/pixel shaders. Also, any source code from that book is not able to run properly. But the structure of the code is fantastic.

Rastertek is a very unhelpful resource as in that he goes through everything at once in everything. Like asking for a page and getting handed a 500 page book. It is very hard to follow and jump back to use as a resource when it consistantly writes codes as a preparation for another tutorial or to complete a past tutorial.

Is there any resources that anyone recommend that would be worth spending money on or even better, free? It is so much information at times that it is hard to summerize everything so I would love to see short source code examples. Much like Frank d luna, except you know.. effect files and actually working.

Answer (score 3):

I have used the following links in the past. None are ideal or "the complete resource", but by mixing and matching you should gain a good insight on DirectX in general. Also be sure to check out the `DX11 SDK and MSDN samples`

- http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/gclassy/DirectCompute-Expert-Roundtable-Discussion/
- http://microsoftpdc.com/Sessions/P09-16
- http://www.rorydriscoll.com/
- http://www.yakiimo3d.com/
- http://gpuexperiments.blogspot.com/
- http://users.skynet.be/fquake/
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/directx/archive/2010/06/15/introducing-the-directcompute-lecture-series.aspx
- http://www.braynzarsoft.net
- [http://www.amazon.com/dp/1936420228/?tag=stackoverfl08-20](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1936420228)
- [http://www.amazon.com/dp/1435458958/?tag=stackoverfl08-20](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1435458958)